# Server App on Heroku is not accessibe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, heroku

Hi we have a Ruby on Rails server application on Heroku, but when I send a post request to it, I always get a 400 Bad Request response.  I have searched other 400 errors, but none are related to our issue.  The HTTP response that we receive looks like this below:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>
> Server: Cowboy
>
> Date: Fri, 14 Aug 2015 21:55:25 GMT
>
> Content-Length: 0

The post request that I am sending looks like this below:

> POST http://ourapp.herokuapp.com/api/v1/requests HTTP/1.0
>
> Accept-Language: en-us
>
> Accept: text/plain
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> Content-Length: 38
>
> Connection: Close
>
> request=600&key=&newKey=danasecretkey&

Sorry, I had to put blank lines after each header or it would all show up on one line.

If I create an HTML form to send the data, there is no issue.  It's when I then try to send the same request from our file server, that I get the errors. I tried using a preflight request with all of the correct request headings, but received the same 400 Bad Request error.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Check your server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed it was switching from HTTP1.0 to HTTP1.1, adding the host header and changing the uri.

The logs didn't tell us anything, and the params were ok.  The problem was not fully grasping the HTTP header requirements.

Comment: No problems. You should mark your own answer as accepted (V-shaped mark near it) to show people that you've resolved your request.

Comment: Yeah.  It won't let me set my own answer as accepted until tomorrow.

Thanks,

Dana

Answer (score 1):

Well, just guessing from what you've said:

> request=600&key=&newKey=danasecretkey&

It's likely that you have something like `params.require(:key)` in your controller. And your request is missing that parameter.

Rails will respond with 400 status in case you missed some `require`'d params.

Comment: Thanks EugZol.  I don't have access to the Rails server or Heroku.  Another developer is looking after that end.  I've sent him an email to verify that the params match.  This sort of thing often ends up being something silly like that.  Sometimes staring at the same thing for a long time makes it difficult to see the obvious.  I don't mind the embarrassment if this solves it.  Thanks again.

Dana